# How to schedule a mysql stored procedure in windows?

Tags: mysql

Need to schedule in windows 2003 server to run a MySql Stored Procedure weekly once. I tried with batch file but it dint work for me. Any ideas? Thanks in ADV.

Comment: look on http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/42887

Comment: i found the answer myself. here it is,

Comment: @echo off
mysql --user=root --password=root --database=test<test.txt
exit

Comment: save the above code in bat file. In test.txt, i can call procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Are you running mySQL version 5.1 or later?  If so use a [mysql event.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

For example:

```
CREATE EVENT MY_WEEKLY_THING
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS '2010-09-19 23:30:00'
DO CALL MY_STORED_PROCEDURE;
```

Your server will need to be up and running at the time mentioned, of course.

Comment: actually iam using mysql server 5.0. is there any way around using windows scheduled task to work on this?

Comment: The event feature was only added at version 5.1.  There are lots of good reasons to upgrade. But, if you can't, you could, as you mentioned, use a windows scheduled task to do this routine operation.