# Can't schedule a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

What am I doing wrong here?  I just want procedure to be run daily.

```
CREATE EVENT my_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
BEGIN
CALL my_procedure("foo");
END $$
```

Or

```
CREATE EVENT my_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO CALL my_procedure("foo");
```

And get

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EVENT my_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
BEGIN
CALL my_procedure' at line 1
```

Comment: The second one worked for me.

Comment: What is the version of MySQL you're using? MySQL 5.1.6 and later supports this

Comment: Could it be a version issue?  I'm on 5.0.77

Comment: Was typing this at the same time @Christian That's a shame, do you know of any workaround for short term?

Comment: I could make a bash script to call the procedure and cron it I suppose.

Comment: Please put your version comment as an answer and I'll tick it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

Check if event scheduler is off

```
select @@event_scheduler
```

if its off you have to toogle it to on

```
SET @@global.event_scheduler = ON;
```

if the mysql server shutsdown the event scheduler would again turn off

Comment: Unknown system variable 'event_scheduler'. I'm using MySQL 5.5 on Amazon RDS. What should I do to use MySQL Event Scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, then

[How to schedule a mysql stored procedure in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745207/how-to-schedule-a-mysql-stored-procedure-in-windows)

the comments to this question show how to create a batch file to be run as a scheduled job that will call the procedure.

Comment: I'm not using Windows, but don't worry, I've already made a bash script.  Thanks.