# query which runs on a particular time

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, phpmyadmin

I want to write a query which runs on a particular time.

For example when a set time comes the query automatically get executed.

Like if a user register in a website and doesn't verify his/her email in 2 days then the data entry for that user should deleted by a delete query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need a scheduled event reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html, that can run one a day let say. 
Assumed that if the user verify the mail (like click on a link) will generate an entry in your db, then you can check if (current_day - register_day) > 2 days then record status 'expired' and all records having 'expired' status are eligible for delete.

Related questions : 
[Can't schedule a stored procedure in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189759/cant-schedule-a-stored-procedure-in-mysql)
and
[How to schedule a stored procedure in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560639/how-to-schedule-a-stored-procedure-in-mysql)

Hope this helps